# Refresh View Controller after calling dismissViewControllerAnimated from View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

What is the most appropriate method for reloading my view controller?

To expand upon the scenario, I have a *UITableView* having populated cells within a View Controller.
I create new cells by transitioning to a new "Create Cell" view controller, however when I call the `dismissViewControllerAnimated` function, the new cell does not appear.
I cannot use a *segue* as the initial view controller is a component of a tab bar view controller, so the tab bar disappears if I *segue* from the "Create Cell" view controller.

Then how can I reload the view, upon a successful dismissal of the "Create Cell" view controller?

Thanks in advance.

Code, in question, that needs refreshing (Implemented the non-working notification method):

```
@interface MyListings ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton     *createListingButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView  *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic)        ListingModel *listItem;
@property (strong, nonatomic)        UserModel    *usr;

@end

@implementation MyListings

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(newCellCreated:)
                                                 name:@"newCellCreated"
                                               object:nil];

    self.listItem = [[ListingModel alloc] init];
    self.usr      = [[UserModel alloc]init];

    NSDate *currentDateTime = [NSDate date];

    FIRUser *user = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;

    if ([self.usr getDataForUser:user.email])
    {
        if ([self.listItem getDataForUser:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.usr.user_id]])
        {
            NSLog(@"Got listings");
        };
    }

    titles = self.listItem.title;
    currentBids = self.listItem.starting_bid;
    stillAvailables = self.listItem.timer;
    listingIDs = self.listItem.listing_id;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY/MM/dd"];

    for(int idx = 0; idx < [self.listItem.listing_id count]; idx++)
    {
        NSDate *d1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:self.listItem.timer[idx]];
        if([d1 compare:currentDateTime] == NSOrderedDescending)
        {
            stillAvailables[idx] = @"Expired";
        }
        else
        {
            stillAvailables[idx] = @"Available";
        }
    }

    _createListingButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    _createListingButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
    _createListingButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    [_createListingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(createListingButtonHighlightBorder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [_createListingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(createListingButtonUnhighlightBorder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_createListingButton addTarget:self action:@selector(createListingButtonUnhighlightBorder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (void) newCellCreated:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"newCellCreated"])
        [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)createListingButtonHighlightBorder
{
    _createListingButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.61 green:0.00 blue:0.02 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
}

- (void)createListingButtonUnhighlightBorder
{
    _createListingButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return titles.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyListingsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyListingsTableViewCell"];
    [cell updateCellWithTitle:[titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] currentBid:[currentBids objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stillAvailable:[stillAvailables objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] listingID:[listingIDs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"editListing" sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"editListing"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        EditListing *destController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destController.listId = self.listItem.listing_id[indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use notification ?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: There are multiple different approach you can use to achieve what you would like. 
You can either create a `delegate` method, `NSNotification`, or a callback `block`. Please show us some code and we can see what would be the best approach among those for you.

Comment: My computer is, currently, indisposed. I can't really add any code, at this moment. But, to describe the view controller, it only contains what's necessary to instantiate prototype cells, which reside within a table view, with properties that are equated to elements of various arrays. So, it's a simple table view class, that contains table view cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have notification or delegate methods.

As you didn't post any piece of code, replace the names as your convenience.

I'll give you a short example using notification.

In your TableViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "newCellCreated"), object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

In your CreateCellViewController:

```
func closeView() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "newCellCreated"))
    }
}
```

**EDIT - Objective C version**

In your TableViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(newCellCreated:)
                                                 name:@"newCellCreated"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void) newCellCreated:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"newCellCreated"])
        [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

In your CreateCellViewController:

```
-(void) closeView {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         postNotificationName:@"newCellCreated"
         object:self];
    }];
}
```

Comment: I sort of get it, only I use Objective-C... So I'll try and find equivalent functions.

Comment: added the objective c version

Comment: Great. I'm glad to help

Comment: Actually, never mind. There was an issue, it ended up not working... :\

Comment: The issue is that the refreshed view doesn't actually show the new cell, anymore.

Comment: Dude, the cell must be shown if you are adding it to your data source in the VC that you use to create the cell. Are you adding new data to your data source ?

Comment: Yes. It's very strange, the only way for the new cells to show is to actually perform a segue to this view controller...

Comment: Without code will be very hard to figure. Try posting some pieces and we try to help you.

Comment: Ok, I shall post some in a while.

Comment: Code posted @GIJOW, hopefully that's helpful.

Comment: This is one part. Where are you posting the notification ? Another view controller if I understood, where you create new "cell"

Comment: Indeed, in another VC where I create the cell. I can add just the implementation component of this in the other cell, if you require it.